# easywsclient websocket connection issues

Tags: c++, web, websocket

I am using https://github.com/dhbaird/easywsclient

The following code wont connect properly, ws comes back as a NULL always and the connection "stucks".

```
using easywsclient::WebSocket;
ws = WebSocket::from_url("ws://mysite.net:80/app/");

assert(ws);
```

I tried debuggin it and at easywsclient.cpp (github link above) line 514 (code below) gives really weird values for "status" and this is where it fails it seems. I can't figure out why this is happening, the webapp works fine in my browser

```
if (sscanf(line, "HTTP/1.1 %d", &status) != 1 || status != 101) { fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Got bad status connecting to %s: %s and status is %d", url.c_str(), line, status); return NULL; }
```

This is somewhat new terrority to me so I clearly am not understanding something. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What is the contents of `line` when you get problems?

Comment: line 0x00000048adcfe6c0 "HTTP/1.1 408 Request Time-out\r\n"

this what it shows in debugger.. didn't think of checking this for some reason